# How a nullable DateTime be given default value when null in a Visual Studio 2012 Report (.sdlc)

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sdlc

I am working on a Visual Studio 2012 Report (.sdlc) using an object data source.  The object data source has a nullable DateTime? property.  I would like to display "-" when null and then format the date as 'dd-MMM-yy' when not null.

I have tried the following expressions, but always received "#Error" in the TextBox on the report.

Note: The 'Format' propery on the TextBox is set to 'dd-MMM-yy' in the these two attempts.

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value), "-", Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value)

=IIf(IsDate(Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value), "-", Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value)
```

I thought the 'Format' property was relying on a DateTime type, so I tried converting the value to a string in the expression, but still got the '#Error'

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value), "-", FormatDateTime(Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate))

=IIf(IsDate(Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value), "-", FormatDateTime(Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate))
```

How can I show a "-" for null DateTime values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have something else going one because I tried

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value), "-", Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value)
```

with the Format property set to `dd-MMM-yy` and got the dashes for null dates.

I also tried

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value), "-", FormatDateTime(Fields!OpenInDRMADate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate))
```

with no Format property and again got dashes for nulls.

This was in VS2008.

Maybe you have another expression (for example, for Color) on that object that is causing a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with date in a header textbox.

=IIF(ISDATE(Fields!LICENCEDDATE.value) = False, "",
formatdatetime(IIF(IsDate(Fields!LICENCEDDATE.value) ="1",Fields!LICENCEDDATE.Value,"01/01/1900"),dateformat.ShortDate))

This works

I just don't understand

formatdatetime(IIF(IsDate(Fields!LICENCEDDATE.value) ="1" <-- what does the "1" for???

Comment: Please post questions as a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This is the answers section.